# How to find the enclosing class of a Python method in Emacs

Tags: python, emacs

While coding in Python in Emacs, is there a shortcut to find (or to navigate to) the start of a method's enclosing class?

Example:

```
class Foo(object):
.
.
.
.
    def bar_method():
```

While editing bar_method, how can I move to (or identify) the start of class Foo?

I'm using the standard Python mode but am open to suggestions for replacements. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`python-mode` as found at https://github.com/fgallina/python.el (included in current stable Emacs 24.3) provides <kbd>C-c C-u</kbd> binding for `python-beginning-of-block`. First invocation will go to to the beginning of the method containing point, the second -- as point is no longer in a method but rather in a class definition -- will send you to the beginning of containing class.

*UPD: I stand corrected, most recent version of `python.el` @ github provides the same functionality by overriding `beginning-of-defun`, which is bound to `C-M-a` by default.*

Comment: this seems to jump to the begining of the previous method in the class, not the class, for me.